# How the ADF faces lifecycle is different from JSF lifecylce?

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

This [highly voted answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2168741/1527084) says that ADF faces has a longer lifecycle than JSF . I want to know what are the differences between the two lifecycles and what benefits do those couple of extra lifecycle phases of ADF provide ?

P.S: I am well aware of the JSF lifecycle but I am new to ADF . So you can base your answer on this premise.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11668722)

Comment: Basically what I see that oracle has done is stretch out parts of the standard jsf lifecycle into separate phases (validateInputValues and validateModelUpdates) which I imagine comes from the fact that ADF provides a data binding model as well as the component framework. Metadatacommit and prepare render corresponding to the view delta calculation that is done normally in jsf render response and restore view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differences between JSF and ADF life cycles are documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/web.1111/b31974/adf_lifecycle.htm

Comment: +1 for the link . But can you put a short answer that describes the key differences in the two life cycles . The links may become redundant over time and the information may be lost .